# Is this form alignment possible in Bootstrap 2?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have an old app that uses Bootstrap 2 and the wireframes for a new feature requires me to put a checkbox below a label, but by the side of a multiline textbox.

This picture illustrate the situation:

[image]

All of my fields use the following structure:

```
<div class="row-fluid extended-row">
   <div class="span6">
       <div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label" for="<%=txtMyField.ClientID %>">
                                    My Field</label>
           <div class="controls">
               <asp:TextBox class="input-large" ID="txtMyField" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
           </div>
   </div>
.
.
.
.
</div>
```

So I don't know how to position the checkbox below as I think that using form layout on bootstrap doesn't allow you to put controls below and next to the label. 
Is this possible using bootstrap 2?

Comment: Certainly, it looks like the left input and checkbox could be inside a `.span5`, the multiline textbox on the right in a `.span7`, and the checkbox aligned to the right with `.pull-right`. Can't get any more specific than that if you haven't attempted any code yet, though. Try building the structure first, and if you run into some unsolvable layout issues, then bring your question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi apologies for that. I edited my question and added the current layout that I'm using. I tried using .span like you said, but the field and its label were not aligning to the rest of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way of doing this. I can't still align the label to the top, but the result is good enough

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
        <label class="control-label" for="<%= txtCommentary.ClientID %>">Commentary</label><br />
        <input id="chkRepeatfailure" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
       <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" class="input-xlarge" ID="txtCommentary" runat="server"
                            placeholder="" />                                  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the classes for bootstrap 2 but I believe that they should be similar to that of bootstrap3. Try using the col-md-offset class or pull-right.

[offsetting columns in bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)